# Why the letters are capitalized in my reference?

Tags: bibliographies

In my Overleaf file, I want to cite the following reference and I use the code.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{B2019}
A.~Bob.
\newblock Red Sheep.
\newblock {\em J. ABC} {\bf 33} (2019), 347--360.

\end{thebibliography}
```

While the title of the output is "Red Sheep", rather than "Red sheep" as I want. I am wondering is it possible to fix it? (Without changing to `\newblock Red sheep.`)

Comment: you are writing the list by hand rather than use bibtex or biblatex (overleaf is not involved here, other than hosting your tex system) so there is no automation it is exactly like an `enumerate` list. You get the text that you write.

Comment: Please show a full minimal example that others can copy? Did you type this code manually or did it come from `bibtex`. If manually then just change it.

Comment: I see. I type it manually rather than bibtex to avoid the annoying copy and paste bibitem procedure in the end.

Comment: what copy and paste??? If you use bibtex you never need to see the bibitem at all, it is all handled in the background.

Comment: But when you submit your paper to a journal, it is better to copy and paste the bibitem to the main tex file? So you only submit the .tex file, without the. bib file?

Comment: @Connor it depends on the journal, some would prefer bibtex (so they can restyle it) but if they don't accept bibtex just change `\bibliography{foo}` to `\input{\jobname.bbl}`  at the end, or even if you want a single file, making a single copy of a region of generated text must surely be orders of magnitude simpler than writing equivalent text by hand,

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the list by hand rather than use `bibtex` or `biblatex`  so there is no automation: it is exactly like an `enumerate` list. You get the text that you write.